# ¿Cómo funciona la replicación en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Quería preguntarles a los experimentados cómo funciona más precisamente la réplica de "Maestro-Esclavo" de MySQL, ya que no entiendo lo siguiente:

Supongamos que tengo dos listas de registros que se numeran del 1 al 5, pero los valores y los datos que contienen las dos listas son diferentes.

Según entiendo, la réplica lo que haría sería mover los 5 registros faltantes de cada tabla a la otra para que las dos queden iguales. ¿Verdad?.

En este caso, ¿Quedarían dos tablas de 10 registros o reemplazaría los 5 del esclavo para poner los 5 del maestro en su lugar?

Quizás fui confuso, mi duda principalmente es que pasa con las claves de cada tabla.

¿Cómo funciona específicamente la réplica?

Comment: No funciona así. La replicación funciona a través del [registro binario o de transacciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html). Toda modificación hecha a la base de datos es escrita en dicho registro, y ese registro se va enviando en forma de corriente de datos al otro extremo, donde se replicarán los cambios que vienen reflejados en él.

Comment: He terminado de redactar una extensa respuesta que espero que satisfaga tus dudas. Si algo no te queda claro no dudes en preguntarlo dejándome un comentario en la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No funciona como lo describes en la pregunta. A continuación te explico, sin entrar en detalles técnicos, cómo se realiza.

El funcionamiento de la replicación se basa en el [registro binario o de transacciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html) que genera el servidor MySQL.

Toda modificación hecha a la base de datos es escrita en dicho registro, y ese registro se va enviando en forma de corriente de datos a petición de los servidores secundarios conectados, los cuales replicarán los cambios que vienen reflejados en él.

---

En la [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html) puedes encontrar lo siguiente:

> The binary log contains “events” that describe database changes such as table creation operations or changes to table data. It also contains events for statements that potentially could have made changes (for example, a DELETE which matched no rows), unless row-based logging is used. The binary log also contains information about how long each statement took that updated data. The binary log has two important purposes:
>
> - For replication, the binary log on a replication source server provides a record of the data changes to be sent to replicas. The source sends the information contained in its binary log to its replicas, which reproduce those transactions to make the same data changes that were made on the source. See Section 17.2, “Replication Implementation”.
> - Certain data recovery operations require use of the binary log. After a backup has been restored, the events in the binary log that were recorded after the backup was made are re-executed. These events bring databases up to date from the point of the backup. See Section 7.5, “Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery”.
>
> The binary log is not used for statements such as SELECT or SHOW that do not modify data. To log all statements (for example, to identify a problem query), use the general query log. See Section 5.4.3, “The General Query Log”.

En castellano:

> El registro binario contiene los “eventos” que describen cambios en la base de datos como la creación de tablas o cambios a los datos de una tabla. Además contiene eventos eventos para declaraciones que podrían haber realizado cambios (por ejemplo, un `DELETE` que no coincidió con ningún registro), a menos que se utilice el registro basado en filas. El registro binario también contiene información sobre cuánto tiempo tomó a cada declaración actualizar esos datos. El registro binario tiene dos importantes propósitos:
>
> - Para la replicación, el registro binario del servidor de origen de la replicación proporciona un registro de los cambios de datos que se van enviando a las réplicas. El origen envía la información contenida en su registro binario a sus réplicas, que reproducen esas transacciones para realizar los mismos cambios de datos que se realizaron en el origen. Consulte la sección 17.2, “Implementación de la Replicación”.
> - Ciertas operaciones de recuperación de datos requieren el uso del registro binario. Una vez que se ha restaurado una copia de seguridad, los eventos en el registro binario que se registraron después del momento en el que se realizó la copia de seguridad se vuelven a ejecutar. Estos eventos actualizarán las bases de datos desde el momento de la copia de seguridad. Consulte la Sección 7.5, “Recuperación Punto-en-el-Tiempo (Incremental)”.
>
> El registro binario no se utiliza para declaraciones como `SELECT` o `SHOW` porque no modifican datos. Para registrar todas las declaraciones (por ejemplo, para identificar una consulta que podría dar problemas), utilice el registro de consultas normal. Consulte la Sección 5.4.3, “El registro de consultas”.

---

En la [Sección 17.2 Implementación de la Replicación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-implementation.html) tienes también lo siguiente:

> Replication is based on the source server keeping track of all changes to its databases (updates, deletes, and so on) in its binary log. The binary log serves as a written record of all events that modify database structure or content (data) from the moment the server was started. Typically, SELECT statements are not recorded because they modify neither database structure nor content.

En castellano:

> La replicación se basa en un servidor de origen que realiza el seguimiento de todos los cambios en sus bases de datos (actualizaciones, borrados, etc) en su registro binario. El registro binario sirve como un histórico de todos los eventos que modifican la estructura o el contenido (datos) de la base de datos desde el momento en que se inició el servidor. Normalmente las sentencias `SELECT` no se registran porque no modifican ni la estructura ni el contenido de la base de datos.

---

Además, debes entender que si en las réplicas (vamos a usar la terminología "primario/réplica" en vez de "maestro/esclavo") se realizan modificaciones que puedan colisionar con el proceso de replicar los cambios del primario, [la replicación se detendrá con un mensaje de error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/8.0/en/replication-features-slaveerrors.html) y habrá que corregirlo manualmente antes de que ésta pueda continuar:

> If a statement produces different errors on the source and the replica, the replication SQL thread terminates, and the replica writes a message to its error log and waits for the database administrator to decide what to do about the error.

En castellano:

> Si una declaración produce errores diferentes en el primario y en la réplica, el proceso de replicación finaliza y la réplica escribe un mensaje en su registro de errores esperando a que el administrador de la base de datos decida qué hacer con el error.

---

Este comportamiento no es único ni exclusivo de MySQL ni su replicación, si no que es un componente muy común en la gran mayoría de gestores de bases de datos (para ser usado en tareas de replicación o no):

- [Documentación de MS SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server).
- [Documentación de PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial).
- [Documentación de Oracle v12](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20295_01/html/821-1222/gazdw.html).

Comment: Creo que esto deja mas que respondida la pregunta. Muchas gracias